# DJI SDK implement Helper.install() in android dynamic function

Tags: android, helper, dji-sdk, dynamic-function

I want to implement DJI functions in a dynamic model(), but to do that it needs cal function Helper.install() in Application class while base model do not know anything about DJI SDK.

There are anyways to go around this?

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. What is DJI. Please don't use abbreviations

Comment: DJI is not an abbreviation. It's a drone company. If you have no clue, then this is not an answer for you to reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the current SDK I see no good solution; the install() accesses information only available in the Application class.

You need to have your own Application class so it can extend MultiDexApplication (yes, DJI's sample shows the code making a call MultiDex.install(this); but the more "Android" correct way is to have you application class extend MultiDexApplication).

So you need the Application class anyway.

I don't fully understand what you mean by a "base model" but my information above would apply no matter what (or how) you are implementing.